# A function to find if a given number is prime

Tags: c

I am a beginner and I am learning functions. Following is the code I have written to find if the given number is a prime. But when ever I execute it, I get the dialogue box saying "project.exe has stopped working". I am using dev c++ . any problem with my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int prime (int i);
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    b=prime(a);
    if (b==1)
    printf("prime");
    else
    printf("not prime");
    return 0;
}
int prime (int i)
{
    int j=0;
    for (j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if (i%j==0)
        break;
    }
    if (j==i)
    return 1;
    else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On your first pass through the `j` loop, `j` is zero. You can't divide by zero or take the remainder of such a division. Start the loop with `j = 2`, because the remainder of a division by one is always zero. Likewise for the upper bound: `i%j` is zero when `i == j`. After all, a prime number is divisible by one and by itself.

Comment: Further, if your termination condition is `j <= i`, `j` will not equal `i` if you run through the whole loop without breaking out of it. It is better to return 0 immediately instead of beraking out of the loop.

Comment: You should change the function to `bool prime (int i)` and return `true` or `false`. Naming it `is_prime` instead might also be a good idea, to indicate that it has a boolean result.

Comment: the natural numbers 0 and 1 are not primes, so the `prime()` function should start `j` with 2.

Comment: when getting input from the user, the code should always prompt the user.  When calling `scanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  No negative number can be 'prime' so should use all `unsigned` numbers, not `int`

Comment: when naming a function, the name should indicate what the function does.  Suggest using `isPrime()` rather than `prime()`

Comment: for readability, indent the body of a code block (if, else) even if only a single line in the body

Comment: regarding this line: `if (b==1)`,  if an 'oops' is made and the code was: `if (b=1)`, the compiler would not catch it.  Suggest: `if (1==b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code block of your prime function:

```
    int j=0;
    for (j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if (i%j==0)
        break;
    }
```

to:

```
    int j;
    for (j=2;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if (i%j==0)
        break;
    }
```

When you are trying to find the `mod` it actually tries to find it by division operation. You cannot divide a number by zero, as `j` is initially zero, you program is crashing.

Comment: I am not talking about the efficiency of prime finding algorithm. I just suggested to solve the problem of programming crashing. By the way, I have edited the answer.

Comment: Downvote revoked. This will also ensure that 1 and smaller numbers are not marked prime. `j <= i` can `j < i`.

Answer (score 1):

It should start from `2`, not from `0`. `0` causes division by zero and that's cause why your program stops. Correct is:

```
int j;
for (j=2;j<i;j++)
{
    if (i%j==0)
    break;
}
if (j==i)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
// or simply return j == i;
```

Comment: I dont need to put j<=i? if the ending condition is j<i, j will take values only untill i-1, doesn't it?

Comment: @Vamshi: Yes. But you don't want to test the divisibility of the number with itself, because the test will succeed and you will wrongly mark the prime as non-prime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a value that is not one. Something like this ...

```
int prime (int i) {
    int j;

    if (i <=3) return 1;
    for (j=2;j<i/2;j++)
        if (i%j==0) return j;

    return 1;
}
```

Checking if the number `i` is greater than 3 is also important.

Comment: He is just trying to write a function that gives a boolean result: Is prime? true or false. He is just using int instead of bool, for reasons unknown.

Comment: I think he is using C, which originally didn't have a bool. After C++ came out, I think everyone is used to thinking in bool.